# Timesheet created and needs approval workflow - getting 'Access Denied' when supervisor opens google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a timesheet in google sheets and I have a button to 'Send Email to Approver.' I'm using the code below to email to the supervisor. It copies the original file and I believe that's where the 'Access Denied' issue is coming into play - because the supervisor has a different Google account. Even though I've given the supervisor permission to the folder, and I thought they would be able to open anything in that folder, it appears that cannot happen when the file is newly created? I need the supervisor to fill their name in a box before sending to Payroll - so a .pdf file does not work for me.

```
function EmailSupervisor() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var MyNewBook = ss.copy("A Copy of " + ss.getName() + ss.getRange('C3').getValue()); 
  var MyLink = MyNewBook.getUrl();
  var MyUser = ss.getRange('C49').getValue(); MailApp.sendEmail({ to: MyUser, subject: 'Payroll Hours Approval Needed', body: MyLink, }); 
}
```

Is their a way to code around the 'Access Denied' issue? Or would setting up a Shared Folder take care of the issue? I've read so much at this point, my head is spinning.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The easiest is to share the new file with the supervisor with the [addEditor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditoremailaddress) request

Sample:

```
function EmailSupervisor() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var MyNewBook = ss.copy("A Copy of " + ss.getName() + ss.getRange('C3').getValue());
  MyNewBook.addEditor(emailAddress)
  var MyLink = MyNewBook.getUrl();
  var MyUser = ss.getRange('C49').getValue(); 
  MyNewBook.addEditor(MyUser);
  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: MyUser, subject: 'Payroll Hours Approval Needed', body: MyLink, }); 
}
```

If the issue persists it's possible that your supervisor is signed in wiht multiple accounts into his browser session. In this case ask him to sign out from all accounts apart from the one with which you share the file.

Comment: Beautiful - It worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!!!